# Finding values of x in 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently studying some further maths because I will need to take these units alongside a future PHD in chemical engineering. One of the topics I'm looking at is matrices and I've been finding these to be relatively okay but just a couple of questions have stomped me. I've sorted one now and completely understand how the answer is derived.

The other one asks me to find possible values that x can take given that:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} x^2&3\\1&3x\end{bmatrix}$

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 3&6\\2&x\end{bmatrix}$

Also, 
$AB = BA$

So I can figure out that the two are equal to each other by taking the determinant option. However because I have not seen a question of this standing before, I do not know where I am supposed to go with regards to x.

What would be the most logical step for me. Do I need to go down the divide by det route?

Thanks for any guidance on this issue!

Comment: Just compute the products $AB, BA$. Then set them as equals, and solve the resulting 4 equations for x.

Comment: So I'll multiply them together and then write the matrices out in full, but still as AB = BA.

Will the resulting 4 equations come from x1 multiplied by x1 and so on and so forth?

Comment: When you say `x1 multiplied by x1`, do you mean $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right] \odot\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&4 \end{smallmatrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1a&2b\\3c&4d \end{smallmatrix} \right]$?  If so, that is incorrect.  That would be the "hadamard product" of matrices, not the usual matrix product.

Comment: Also worth noting, your matrices above appeared as one line, (x^2 3)(1 3x), instead of as you probably intended as $\begin{pmatrix} x^2&3\\1&3x\end{pmatrix}$.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to properly format mathematics on this site using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Finally, You can tell if two matrices are **different** if their determinants are different, but you cannot conclude that the two matrices are the same if their determinants are the same.  $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\7&0\end{bmatrix}$ both have determinant equal to zero, but are clearly different matrices.

Comment: Thanks for all of the wisdom above. Yes I did mean what you have stated. Thank you for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you know that $AB=BA$, so multiply the matrices together to get four equations:

$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}x^2&3\\1&3x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3&6\\2&x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3x^2+6&6x^2+3x\\3+6x&6+3x^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, do the same for $BA$:

$$BA=\begin{bmatrix}3&6\\2&x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x^2&3\\1&3x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3x^2+6&9+18x\\2x^2+x&6+3x^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $AB=BA$, you can compare the two termwise:

$$\begin{bmatrix}3x^2+6&6x^2+3x\\3+6x&6+3x^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3x^2+6&9+18x\\2x^2+x&6+3x^2\end{bmatrix}$$

So, there are 4 equations to compare here to solve for x.

$$
\begin{align}
3x^2+6&=3x^2+6\\
6x^2+3x&=9+18x\\
3+6x&=2x^2+x\\
6+3x^2&=6+3x^2
\end{align}
$$

Obviously the top and bottom ones cancel out – they're true regardless of the value of $x$. So, solve the middle two:

$$
\begin{align}
6x^2-15x-9&=0\\
2x^2-5x-3&=0
\end{align}
$$

Note that $3(2x^2-5x-3)=6x^2-15x-9$, so you actually only have one polynomial to solve.

Comment: Great I had half of it but not all of it so thanks for the guidance. I have factored the polynomial to give 3(x-3)(2x+1)

Comment: Shall I just put the polynomial through the quadratic formula?

Comment: I have just utilized the quadratic formula and I have derived an answer of x = 3 and x = -0.5

Comment: Thanks for all assistance!